# how to change the background color of my listview based on a given data as a parameter in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-listview

I have an android application that basically scan a barcode. I have a lists of items and I would like to change a color of my list once the item has been scanned.

Please find the image below for reference.

[image]

I would like to change a background color of item to red only if the item remaining is zero. There is a item remaining  filed on the right side.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Please post your recycler view adapter class code here for better understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide code of adapter for batter understanding.
you can do it by conditioning in your recyclerView

for example:

In onBindViewHolder function:

```
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int 
      position) {

      //Get current  item's model  from Arraylist
      ScanModel scanModel = list.get(position);


      int remainingNumber = scanModel.getRemainigNumber();
      if(remaingNumber>1)
      {
      //change background color to white or whatever you have.
           holder.rvBackground.
           setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
      }
      else
      {

         //Change color to red 
         holder.rvBackground.
         setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
   
      }
     //Rest of your code.....

   
      }
```